# Typescript named definition in interface Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say for example I have an interface which defines a boolean value and optional string:

**Example**

```
interface IError {
  error: [boolean, string?];
}
```

Now later in the code I want to use it:

```
if (somethingTrue) {
  error: [false]
} else {
  error: [true, "Error occurred because of foo"]
}
```

I got this working. However, I would like to add more context to the Interface. The boolean should be named `errorOccured` and the string should be named `message`.

**Tried**

I was thinking about the following:

```
interface IError {
  error: [errorOccured: boolean, message: string?];
}
```

Might be something obvious that I'm missing, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an existing feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28259) for named tuples in TypeScript, but they are not currently supported.

In the mean time, you can either use the unnamed tuple like you have, or use an object:

```
interface IError {
  errorOccurred: boolean;
  message?: string;
}
```

Another option depending on your use case may be for `errorOccurred` to be implicit based on whether there is an error object at all or whether it has a `message`.

Answer (score 1):

With the name of your interface, I would have directly put the properties into it :

```
interface IError {
  errorOccurred: boolean;
  message?: string;
}
```

and your object `error` should be of type `IError`.

And for the implementation of this interface, you can set independantly both parameters...